# Why can't select come first in a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

In a LINQ query, the order of operators is `from`-`where`-`select`:

```
int[] numbers = new int[7] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

var numQuery = from num in numbers
               where (num % 2) == 0
               select num;
```

If we put the `select` clause first like in traditional `select`-`from`-`where` SQL, it fails to compile:

```
var numQuery = select num            // error: ; expected
               from num in numbers
               where (num % 2) == 0;
```

What is the reason behind this restriction?

Comment: select coming first in SQL is just to simulate natural language. SQL was meant as a language that managers can program... Turns out they still can't. Logically it makes no sense because select is processed *after* everything else (even in SQL).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What is the reason behind this restriction?

I believe the primary reason was actually Intellisense. Until an IDE knows what sort of collection you're using, it can't suggest which properties you want to use from the elements of that collection. The way the syntax works now, by the time you're writing a `select` or `where` clause, the IDE can tell what the element type is and make suggestions.

I would say it also has the benefit of making a lot more sense by putting the query in chronological order: you start with a source, filter it, transform it etc and end up with a result.

Finally, I suspect it makes the language transform from query expressions into "normal" C# (typically using extensions methods) simpler to express.

I think it would be more reasonable to ask why SQL is expressed backwards :)

Comment: Perfect explanation.  May make sense to work backwards from var numQuery = numbers.Where(num => (num%2) == 0) to further illustrate the choice in syntax order.

Comment: `SQL` instructions are structured like English sentence. `SQL` was even initially called `SEQUEL`(Structured English Query Language).

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because this in fact makes more sense. You first need to tell where to get it from before you tell what. I never understood the logic in SQL actually.

It also helps IntelliSense to show the appropriate fields and properties on the objects you are querying.